# How can I throttle my click inputs

Tags: mouse, xinput

My mouse is often registering two click inputs when I press the button. I have confirmed this to be the case with xev. If I could just throttle inputs to even 1 click per .05ms that would probably be enough to stop this behavior and not require me to get a new mouse.

Comment: huh! Haven't had that problem since 1996! libinput debounces mice buttons automatically, usually. What version of libinput are you using (telling us which Linux distro and version of that you're on might suffice for us to tell)

Comment: @MarcusMüller does `f86-input-libinput 1.2.0` answer your question? If not I'm gonna need some help getting the version of libinput I have. Regarding distro, I'm on NixOS mostly using packages from the 23.05 channel.